# Read a JSON object with Javascript (Error)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I've writen this code but it doesn't work. I'm pretty sure it's mostly correct, but I don't know what's wrong with it. The script returns as output "undefined"

------PHP ON SERVER----------------- (http://www.autofficinacicco.it/json.php)

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$conn = new mysqli($nomehost, $nomeuser, $password, "");

$result = $conn->query("SELECT codice, immagine, testo FROM Promozioni");

$outp = array();
 while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
 {
     $outp[]=$rs;    
 }


$conn->close();

echo json_encode($outp);
?>
```

-----JAVA SCRIPT----------------------------------------

```
<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var url = "http://www.autofficinacicco.it/json.php";

 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
 xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    var out = "<table>";

    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
         out+=arr["immagine"];
         out+="</br>";
         out+=arr["codice"];
         out+="</br>";
         out+=arr["testo"];
         out+="</br>";
    }
    out += "</table>"
    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML =out;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Add error text from browser console

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not clear problem statement. What happens? How does this differ from what you expect to happen? What have you done to debug it?

Comment: @Quentin I've checked his document and it appears to be invalid json that is why he's getting problems with parsing it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is not proper document. Change json formating and use json_encode(); function

```
$outp = "[";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{
 if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
 $outp .= '{"Codice":"'  . $rs["codice"] . '",';
 $outp .= '"Testo":"'   . $rs["testo"]        . '",';
 $outp .= '"Immagine":"'. $rs["immagine"]     . '"}'; 
}
$outp .="]";

$conn->close();
```

to

```
$outp = array();
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{
  $outp[] = $rs;
}
$conn->close();
echo json_encode($outp);
```

Comment: I mean yes, the initial question already is ludicrous; but I'd like to mention that this solution really is a security problem since you put every value (field) from the table into the (user) output.
Looking at your reputation, @Robert, I have no doubt you know that and that's only a code example; but I guess the original poster won't...

Comment: Cells are limited in SQL query to "codice, immagine, testo" that is why I didn't have to write separate array.